# Show that $Z(v,f) \oplus Z(w,f) = Z(v+w, f)$ if minimal polynomials are coprime.

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace, cyclic-decomposition

I am currently learning Linear Algebra and just can't finish this one exercise, at least partially...

We are given some field $F$ and the normal vector space $V = K^n$. By $Z(A,v)$ we denote $\left\langle v, Av, A^2v, A^3v,\dots\right\rangle$ where $A$ is just some $n \times n$ matrix. As an added condition we are given that $m_v$ and $m_w$ are coprime with $m_v$ being the normalised polynomial of lowest possible degree such that $m_v(A)v = 0$.
Now the actual task is to show that $Z(A,v) \oplus Z(A, w) = Z(A, v+w)$.

I was already able to show the inclusion $Z(A,v) + Z(A, w) \supseteq Z(A, v+w)$, which was pretty easy and to show that $Z(A, v) \cap Z(A,w) = \{0\}$ I used that $m_v$ and $m_w$ are coprime.
I tried approaching the other inclusion of $Z(A,v) \oplus Z(A, w) \subseteq Z(A, v+w)$ similary by choosing some $x \in Z(A,v) \oplus Z(A, w)$. Then we know that there is a single and clear way to write that as $$x = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A^n(\lambda_nv+\mu_nv).$$
And at this point I dont see how I could show $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A^n(\lambda_nv+\mu_nv) \in Z(A, v+w) = \left\langle v+w, A(v+w), A^2(v+w), A^3v,\dots\right\rangle$ as the left hand side seems way more general than the right hand one. I guess I have to use that $m_v$ and $m_w$ are coprime somewhere here maybe, but I lack a concrete idea...

Already thanks for any help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general element of $Z(A, v) + Z(A, w)$ is of the form $p(A)v + q(A)w$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials which matter up to multiples of $m_v$ and $m_w$ respectively. We wish to show that this is of the form $r(A)(v+w)$ for some polynomial $r$. Observe that $r(A)(v+w) = r(A)v + r(A)w$. Thus, we wish to find some polynomial $r$ such that $r \equiv p \bmod{m_v}$ and $r \equiv q \bmod{m_w}$. Do you see how to proceed?

Comment: Firstly thanks already! Sorry I am already quite tired, so sorry if I am writing nonsense... As we know that $m_v$ and $m_w$ are coprime we can(?) conclude that $r = p \cdot q$, at least it should be true that $pq \equiv p \bmod m_v$ and $pq \equiv q \bmod m_w$. Is that true or at least the right direction? Haha... But it certainly isn't true that $p(A)q(A)v + p(A)q(A)w = p(A)v + q(A)w$, so I don't think my "idea" is right...

Comment: That's not quite right, but here's a concrete example. Let's say that $m_v = x - 3$ and $m_w = x - 4$. Let's also say that $p = x^2 - 2$ and $q = x^2 - 1$. Now, you wish to have $r(x) \equiv x^2 - 2 \pmod{x - 3}$ and $r(x) \equiv x^2 - 1 \pmod{x - 4}$. First, do you see why this is equivalent to $r(3) = 7$ and $r(4) = 15$? Do you see how to construct such a polynomial? In general, this phenomenon is called the Chinese Remainder Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Chinese%20remainder,are%20pairwise%20coprime%20(no%20two